# JavaScript By Reference Object

Tags: javascript, byref

I have code which is similar to

emp1 = emp;

emp= emp2;

if objects are by reference then why emp1 is not equal to emp2?

why emp1 prints "shilpa" instead of "manish" .

```js
var emp = 
    {
      name : "manish",
      number :  10
    }


var emp1 = emp;

var emp2 = 
    {
      name : "shilpa",
      number :  20
    }

emp = emp2;

console.log(emp);
console.log(emp1);
console.log(emp2);
```

Comment: `emp1` prints `manish`

Comment: 1) `emp` is assigned a reference to an object in memory 2) `emp1` is assigned to the reference `emp` is assigned to 3) `emp2` is assigned a difference reference to an object in memory 4) `emp` is assigned to `emp2`'s reference, there's no reason for `emp1`'s reference to change.

Comment: In other words - in JS there is no way to change the variable's value other than explicitly assigning to it.

Comment: The references are to objects, not variables. (This is the same way Java, C#, Ruby, and Python work, for example.)

Comment: @Manish variables are just a pointers to location in memory, `emp` just keeps the address to object, and then You pass that pointer (address) to `emp1`.

Comment: @AndrewLi thanks for your reply, but emp1 is pointing to emp .. thats where i,m getting confused...

Comment: @Manish `emp1` doesn't point to `emp`. As Ryan mentioned, references point to objects in memory, not variables. `emp` points to a reference.

Comment: @Manish watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ooYYRLdg_g explains enough simple

Comment: why negative rating .. common guys...

Comment: @num8er I actually watched that video before posting this question..

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "objects are by reference" mean? This is not standard terminology, and if you use non-standard terminology, you should define it, otherwise it is hard to understand what you mean. The closest standard term is "pass-by-reference" (aka "call-by-reference"), but that doesn't apply here: a) there are no calls and nothing is being passed, and b) ECMAScript is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I tried to explain what I meant by an example.. does it count? or just the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThiS is what happens.

You create a variable `emp` which points to a location in the memory where is stored the object value you defined.

Then you you create a variable `emp1` which points to the same location in memory of the object value.

Then you define a new variable `emp2` which points to a location in the memory where is stored your object value you define.

Then you set that `emp` points to the nrw location in memory of the `emp2` object value.

But `emp1` still points to the first location/object.

I think you are getting confused between variable declarations and passing parameters in methods/functions (by reference or by value)

Comment: Not sure why people are giving negative rating... actually exact problem was with LinkList where I was trying to previous ptr.. i just came up with similar example..but easy to understand... :)

Comment: No idea, I didnt downvote it so you should ask them :) I think that it is because you are getting a bit confused between variable declarations and passing variables by value or by reference

Comment: I didn't vote it for closing but already 3 people did. Anyway, the most important thing is you understand what's going on with that code

Comment: @quirimmo I voted for close as not reproducible. Since even after hours the OP did not check that the actual output does not match with what they claim in the question. Hence - not reproducible.